# How to define enable_if_t based overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I wanted to write a template combination of 2 overloads, as shown in the code below, I wish to do different process on 2 
genres of objects. when compile I got these errors:

```
// Error    C2672   'info': no matching overloaded function found
// and
// // Error C2783   'void info(StrType)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

code is:

```cpp
/// With this commented out, compile fails, while with it uncommented, all cals get 
// in to this void template.
//template<typename T/*,
//typename = void*/>
//void info(T s) {
//
//}

template <typename StrType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::string, StrType>, bool> = false
>
void info(StrType s) {
    std::cout <<"str: "<< s << std::endl;
}


template<typename IntType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<    
    typename std::remove_reference_t<typename std::remove_cv<IntType>>  , 
    int
    >, bool> = false
>
void info(IntType s) {
    std::cout <<"int: "<< s + s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    info("31");  // Error   C2672   'info': no matching overloaded function found
// and
// // Error C2783   'void info(StrType)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'

    info((int)111);  // Same complain as above.
}
```

I was expecting the output be 
str: 31
int: 111
but compiling failed, complaining: 
Error   C2672   'info': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: 2 overloads: `void info(std::string_view);` and `void info(int);` seems to do the job. (and third one `template <typename T> void info(T) = delete;` if you really want to disallow other types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), the 1st template paraemter is `From`, the 2nd one is `To`, so change the template argument order from

```
template <typename StrType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::string, StrType>, bool> = false
>
void info(StrType s)
```

to

```
template <typename StrType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<StrType, std::string>, bool> = false
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
void info(StrType s)
```

For the 2nd overload, you should get the `type` from `std::remove_cv`, not to use itself directly; so change

```
template<typename IntType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<    
    typename std::remove_reference_t<typename std::remove_cv<IntType>>  , 
    int
    >, bool> = false
>
void info(IntType s) {
```

to

```
template<typename IntType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<    
    typename std::remove_reference_t<typename std::remove_cv<IntType>::type>  , 
    //                                                               ^^^^^^
    int
    >, bool> = false
>
void info(IntType s) {
```

or (since C++14)

```
template<typename IntType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<    
    typename std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<IntType>>  , 
    //                                             ^^
    int
    >, bool> = false
>
void info(IntType s) {
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S6qj2XuXgeEVP7XM)

Comment: I would also suggest removing redundant `typename`s when using helper type aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Using `if constexpr` could make your code simpler, more compact and more importantly more readable:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
void info( T s )
{
    if constexpr( std::is_convertible_v< T, std::string > )
    {
        std::cout <<"str: "<< s << std::endl;
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< std::remove_reference_t< std::remove_cv_t< T > >, int > )
    {
        std::cout <<"int: "<< s + s << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "unknown type";
    }
}

int main() {
    info("31"); 
    info((int)111);
    info(1.1);
}
```

Comment: constexpr way! That's cool! Thanks. whereas another earlier answer is kinda more accurate to my question.